# Access opencv structuring element values

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm using opencv with c++ on mac, thus with standard libraries, and I need to access the cells of the structuring element opencv returns to calling

```
    Mat element = getStructuringElement( MORPH_RECT, Size(2*n+1, 2*n+1));
```

How can I access cell values in element?

Comment: Like any other matrix... "element.at<uchar>(row, col)"

Comment: I tried that but when I try to cout the value I just get black space.

Comment: Because you need to cast to int, or you print the ASCII character... "cout << int(element.at<uchar>(row, col));"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the elements of your matrix like any other matrix of type `CV_8UC1`:

```
uchar v = elements.at<uchar>(row, col);
elements.at<uchar>(row, col) = uchar(255);
```

If you need to print out the value with `std::cout`, remember to cast to `int`, or you print the ASCII value, not the actual value:

```
std::cout << elements.at<uchar>(row, col);
```